# How does the system knew that an address being accessed is constant or not

Tags: c, pointers, constants

Writing to a constant variable using a pointer is giving run time error.

```
const int i;
int *p;
void main()
{
    p = (int*)&i;
    *p = 10;         // Causes runtime error
}
```

But in a windows system everything is running from RAM itself.

When I printed the address of const variables and normal variables, I can see that they are in different offsets.

How does the system know that the address being accessed by the pointer is a `const` one?

Comment: The linker has placed the global variable `i` in a RO section of the executable image.

Comment: *p = 10 undefined behaviors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strictly speaking, your code yields undefined behavior according to the C-language standard.

In practice, the linker has probably placed the variable `i` in a RO section of the executable image.

So the write-operation `*p = 10` resulted in a memory-access violation (aka *segmentation fault*).

Comment: Is the RO section residing in RAM itself?

Comment: @AbleEldhose: The rest of my comment here is not something that is dictated by the C-language standard, but basically depends on the underlying platform (operating system, virtual memory, compiler, linker, etc). Typically, the entire executable image is loaded into RAM. Sometimes parts of it may be "swapped out" into the hard-disk, in order to "make room" for other applications. But basically, when it's running - it is running from the RAM (again, depending on your platform - for example, there are HW architectures which run everything from Flash).

Comment: While the executable image is running from RAM, different access-privileges are defined for different sections within that image. For example, the code-section is definitely RO. The stack is RW. The data section (global and/or static variables) is typically divided into RO and RW. But it's not like the RO sections actually reside in a "physically" RO storage unit. It's just that any memory-access attempt goes through the MMU (memory management unit), and if the attempt is illegal, then a bus-fault exception is raised.

Answer (score 4):

> *How does the system knew ....*

Ideally, the *system* does not need to **know**. For objects with `const`-qualified type, the allocation (in general) will be in read-only section, so any attempt to modify (write) will cause access violation. It's the programmer who should know.

> *When I printed the address of `const` variables and normal variables, I can see that they are in different offsets.*

Yes, that's likely, because the *normal* variables reside in read-write memory, whereas `const` variables will reside in read-only memory.

Please notice, there's **no syntax (or compilation) error** for your code snippet. It's only the behavior of the code (runtime) is undefined.

FYI, quoting `C11`, chapter §6.7.3/p6

> If an attempt is made to modify an object defined with a const-qualified type through use
>   of an lvalue with non-const-qualified type, the behavior is undefined. [...]